# Changing values of an Angular ReactiveForm with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, userscripts

I'm making a UserScript to change an Angular ReactiveForm inputs values (as a development tool) ; I'm using the old classic :

```
$('myinput').val('myVal')
```

It's working great, all my inputs have a value but Angular doesn't detect the changes so I've tried to trigger the change event (I even tried keyup, dow, focus... with jQuery & native JavaScript `dispatchEvent`) :

```
trigger('change') // on each inputs & on the form
```

But my ReactiveForm doesn't update its values, how can I perform this task?

Comment: Could you please show more code on your implementation. Just curious though? why mix jQuery with Angular? :-/ ?

Comment: Why? When you can do this with angular?

Comment: It's to have a button (keydown event) to log in automatically on localhost.

Comment: You may have to trigger the native event handler, rather than having jQuery generating the event.  jQuery doesn't necessarily trigger events attached outside of its pervue.  Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d59o14gf/1/

Comment: Still don't need jquery for that you can trigger the keydown with angular event. I suggest you look into angular documentations.

Comment: @penleychan you can do that from a userscript?

Comment: I know, the thing is that it's for the development environment only & it contains sensitive data (mail & password). That's why I want to make a UserScript.

Comment: @Myerffoeg This question addresses dispatching a native event handler.  I'd give that a try.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript